# Using pg_execute, I can't use now() or null values

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm using `pg_prepare` to prepare my SQL statements in PHP. When I try to `pg_execute` with a value that needs to be `NULL`, the function fails. Similarly, it will fail when using the SQL keyword `now()`.

**Code:**

```
pg_prepare($connection, "insert_autosave", 'INSERT INTO autosave (category, editor, session_id, content, timeout, as_hook) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING id');
$result = pg_execute($connection, "insert_autosave", array($category, $editor, $sid, $content, ($sto == "timeout" ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'), (is_numeric($asid) ? $asid : 'NULL')));
```

**Error:**

> [pg_execute]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL" in actions.php on line 49

Doing a normal `pg_query` works. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall you can use PHP's `null` constant for that:

```
$result = pg_execute($connection, "insert_autosave", array(
   $category, 
   $editor, 
   $sid, 
   $content, 
   ($sto == "timeout" ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'), 
   (is_numeric($asid) ? $asid : null)
));
```

This will definitely not work with SQL functions though, you will have to embed these in the statement beforehand:

```
pg_prepare(
   $connection, 
   "insert_autosave", 
   'INSERT INTO autosave (some_date) VALUES (NOW())'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

netcoder already explained how to take care of the NULL case. It's also possible to pass now() via a placeholder, using the special date/time input values "now", "today", etc. ([See documentation for more info](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5573))

```
pg_prepare(
   $connection, 
   "insert_autosave", 
   'INSERT INTO autosave (some_date) VALUES ($1)'
);
pg_execute($connection, "insert_autosave", array('now'));
pg_execute($connection, "insert_autosave", array('2010-01-14 20:24:43'));
```

You can use `$1::timestamp` in cases where there's any ambiguity about the type.

NB! Never use this feature in directly SQL queries like `'now'::timestamp`, because in this case the value will be parsed and remembered at prepare-time, and every execution will get the same time even if it's in a different transaction. `NOW()` is preferred in this case.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because the `null` issue was the more pressing matter and it worked for me. However, your `now` solution worked for the now problem as well. Thank you!

Comment: We're both right :) You cannot pass SQL functions using PDO parameters. Fortunately, Postgres (unlike MySQL) has a special *input value* (not function) for NOW, which I had forgotten. +1 for you.